# Unable to connect to second name of Windows 2008 Server R2 machine from XP

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-xp, windows-server-2008-r2, server-message-block, netbios

I used the command `netdom computername /add:newname.domainname.com` to add a second name to a server running Windows 2008 Server R2. After restarting the server, I had DNS "A" entries for both names. In addition, the second name was added to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters\OptionalNames`, which I believe should have taken care of any NetBIOS resolution.

From my Windows 7 workstation, I can `ping` both names and running `net view` on both names reveals the same list of resources. From Windows XP, I can `ping` both names, but `net view` only works on the first name. Running `net view` on the second name returns:

```
System error 52 has occurred.

You were not connected because a duplicate name exists on the network. Go to System in 
Control Panel to change the computer name and try again.
```

What do I need to do to make the second name usable from XP clients?

**Update**: I was able to resolve the problem by adding the REG_DWORD key `DisableStrictNameChecking = 1` to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters`, then restarting the Server service. However, I do not understand why this was necessary.

Comment: The Update of the question contains the answer that worked for us: DisableStrictNameChecking = 1. Tumba should make an actual answer that can get upvoted, and perhaps add some SMB 1 vs. 2 information. We had this problem when we tried a CNAME (alias) records, or the alternative of a Host(A) DNS records. (We edited our DNS through the GUI in Control Panel | Administrataive Tools | DNS, not through the netdom command.) Note that Win7 computers on the same domain that happened to connect to a Server 2003 logonserver did not have this problem. But XP machines, and Win7 computers that connected to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Windows XP spoke to Windows Server 2008 using Name2, the server responded that it was actually Name1.  Windows XP told you that Name2 was being used for both server Name1, and Server Name2 -- 2 different servers at the same name.

There are two solutions to this problem:

1) Use SMB 2, on Vista/Win7/Server 2008 etc

2) Use SMB 1 on XP, but tell XP not to check the server name when it gets a replay -- Disable Strict Name Checking.