# Connecting to windows 2003 using ipv6-literal: A duplicate name exists on the network

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, ipv6, server-message-block, netbios

I'm trying to connect to Windows 2003 server's share using ipv6 address from Windows Server 2008.

I use ipv6-literal.net conversion as described on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385353.aspx (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/09/15/10061950.aspx)

I see the error "A duplicate name exists on the network".

Why does it occur?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the same as for the question "[Unable to connect to second name of Windows 2008 Server R2 machine from XP](https://serverfault.com/questions/308585/unable-to-connect-to-second-name-of-windows-2008-server-r2-machine-from-xp?rq=1)"

Add an appropriate registry key to your Windows 2003 server as described here:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;281308